# How do I add AllowAnonymousAttribute to a route/request from custom midleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core website that is build with static files and ASP.NET Core routing middleware, so no MVC.

I requiring all request to be authenticated by default.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();            
});
```

I have a mix of middlewares and routing configuration - but how do I specify that some routes of the static files and my custom middleware needs to Allow Anonymous?

Is there a way to `app.Use(...)` and tell the context that authorization has been applied and it should not use the fallback? So my custom middlewares can be set up correctly or am I required to set everything up with endpoint routing and added metadata to the routes?

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<NextJSMiddleware>();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseEndpoints(config =>
{
    ///This is for detecting whether the application process has crashed/deadlocked. If a liveness probe fails, app can be stopped/restarted, or create a new one.
    config.MapHealthChecks("/.well-known/live", new HealthCheckOptions { Predicate = _ => false }).WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute()); ;
    ///Readiness probe. This is for detecting whether the application is ready to handle requests. 
    config.MapHealthChecks("/.well-known/ready").WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute()); 
    config.MapEAVFrameworkRoutes();
  
    config.MapPost("/.auth/login/passwordless", async (httpcontext) =>
    {
     ...
    }).WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute()); 
    config.MapGet("/.auth/login/passwordless/callback", async (httpcontext) =>
    {
     ...
    });
 });
```

Comment: Try setting up an actual (non-fallback) authorization policy and then set up your logic in it (by reading attributes from the endpoint, or other means). If the user is not authenticated, then `HttpContext.User` will be empty, i.e. anonymous. Then grant / reject access to the request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-handler-for-one-requirement . I can provide a demo if you'd like

Comment: But how do i tie ect /account/login request to a policy when its served as a static file?